# Error when convert Libjson 7.6.1 to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

The latest version of Libjson is 7.6.1, there is a known problem with closing tag on line 239. After fixing that when I try to convert this project from Visual Studio 2012, an error will happen:

```
libjson.vcproj: A sub filter with name "Source Files" already exists.
```

Anybody has ideas?

from the .vcproj file:

```
ProjectType="Visual C++"
Version="9.00"
Name="statLibJson"
ProjectGUID="{153A6FE5-40A9-4C31-B0C2-1C68D2E37BEA}"
RootNamespace="statLibJson"
TargetFrameworkVersion="196613"
```

the original version of this project should be Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems on this Visual C Project file. I have worked it out and committed on a
[GitHub repository](https://github.com/arlm/libJSON). Feel free to used it and contribute.

Besides the issues on this file, it is easier to erase all source code reference, import the project settings and put all the files on the VS 20112 project again. The issues on this files are:

- There are references to `VCWebServiceProxyGeneratorTool` that are not compatible with VS 2012
- The tag `File` on lines 229-231 has no closing tag
- The file filters are broken

  ```
  From 101be42472a4c2c553f8d6fa4aa36fc8230d05ef Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
  From: Alexandre Rocha Lima e Marcondes <alexandre.marcondes@gmail.com>
  Date: Thu, 14 Nov 2013 20:52:48 -0300
  Subject: [PATCH] =?UTF-8?q?Fixes=20on=20the=20VOC=C3=8A=202008=20project=20f?=
  =?UTF-8?q?ile=20to=20enable=20VS=202012=20upgrade?=
  MIME-Version: 1.0
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
  Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
  ---
  libjson.vcproj | 10 +---------
  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 9 deletions(-)
  diff --git a/libjson.vcproj b/libjson.vcproj
  index 25d1549..84c50c8 100644
  --- a/libjson.vcproj
  +++ b/libjson.vcproj
  @@ -32,9 +32,6 @@
                 Name="VCXMLDataGeneratorTool"
             />
             <Tool
  -               Name="VCWebServiceProxyGeneratorTool"
  -           />
  -           <Tool
                 Name="VCMIDLTool"
             />
             <Tool
  @@ -93,9 +90,6 @@
                 Name="VCXMLDataGeneratorTool"
             />
             <Tool
  -               Name="VCWebServiceProxyGeneratorTool"
  -           />
  -           <Tool
                 Name="VCMIDLTool"
             />
             <Tool
  @@ -154,9 +148,6 @@
                 Name="VCXMLDataGeneratorTool"
             />
             <Tool
  -               Name="VCWebServiceProxyGeneratorTool"
  -           />
  -           <Tool
                 Name="VCMIDLTool"
             />
             <Tool
  @@ -238,6 +229,7 @@
             <File
                 RelativePath=".\Source\JSONNode_Mutex.cpp"
                 >
  +           </File>
             <File
                 RelativePath=".\Source\JSONPreparse.cpp"
                 >
  -- 
  1.7.11.1
  ```